# How to conditionally render image in case one doesnt load, using the image component provided by nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Im fetching data for an image. The image's src is saved in the variable "movie.primaryImage.url", but there are cases when the image doesnt load, ive tried to implement conditional rendering so when the image doesnt load a fallback one is set. Here is my attempt but it doesnt work. How do i set a fallback image in case the one im fetching doesnt work in nextjs?

```
 {
           movie.primaryImage.url 
           ?
         
         <Image 
          src={movie.primaryImage.url}
          alt={movie.titleText.text}
          height={300}
          width={200}
          />
          :
          <Image 
          src={'https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vecteezy.com%2Fvector-art%2F5337799-icon-image-not-found-vector&psig=AOvVaw3KsJjOSvwjWH-OLH8cJPIT&ust=1702332423213000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBEQjRxqFwoTCJDFlNHwhYMDFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD'}
          alt={movie.titleText.text}
          height={300}
          width={200}
          />
          
          }
          <h2>{movie.titleText.text}</h2>
          <p>Release Year: {movie.releaseYear.year}</p>
          {/* Add more details as needed */}
        </div>
      ))}
```

Answer (score 2):

[from Image props](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image)

```
// - indicates optional props
placeholder="blur"  String                      -
onLoad  onLoad={event => done())}   Function    -
onError onError(event => fail()}    Function    -
loading loading="lazy"  String                  -
```

you should have imageUrl in `useState`

```
const [img,setImage]=useState(movie.primaryImage.url)
```

in `onLoad` and `onError`, you call a callback to set the

```
const handleError = () => {
    setImage(defaultFromPublicFolder);
  };
```

in Image component

```
    <Image 
      src={img}
      alt={movie.titleText.text}
      height={300}
      width={200}
      onError={handleError}
      placeholder="blur"
      />
```

you could set `placeholder="blur"` and I think once image is completely loaded, placeholder will be removed